# Burndown Chart icon not showing up in TFS 2010

Tags: tfs, tfs-reports, tfs-2010

I am using TFS 2010 and scrum template I am using is "Microsoft Visual Studion Scrum 1.0".
I have my Work Items and task added to the product backlog and to the sprint.
My problem is, I don't see any icon or menu to click and see the burn down chart.
When I googled,I found this

"This report requires that the team project collection that contains your team project was provisioned with SQL Server Reporting Services"

My project doesn't have SSRS bind to it.

Is it a must or is there any other work around for this in TFS 2010?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to view the Burndown Report, you need to have SSRS Reporting installed and configured.